# How could Charles Xavier walk in Xmen: The Last Stand?

Tags: marvel, x-men

We see how Charles Xavier getting shot as a young adult (In First Class) and have to sit in a wheelchair. But in the beginning of *The Last Stand* when he visits Jean Grey with Eric he walks, how can this be?